# How to rsync specific files, from multiple folders

Tags: rsync

I have two folders,

```
/home/epi/folder1/
home/epi/folder2/
```

And

```
home/epi/destination/
```

I want to move *.txt files from the first two folders into destination, but there are sometimes 5 files, sometimes 100k.

I want to move a max of 40k files (combined) (no matter how many files are in there). These could be in either folder1 or folder2, so in the first step I generate a list.txt using find and head that contains 40k filenames.

I've tried a few things but am struggling to get both the specific files moved (in the list), due to the fact they could be in either folder. If I use --files-from, it doesn't seem to allow me to use multiple source directories. It takes one, then expects the destination location. If I leave that out, I can specify two source folders and move all the files, but then, I'm moving everything.

I've tried using `` `cat list.txt` ``, but 40k is too large a list of arguments to pass into the rsync. It works fine for smaller numbers, but I don't want the overhead of calling it multiple times for the same list cut into chunks.

a)
    `rsync -O -av --stats --files-from=list.txt --remove-source-files --log-file=test.log /home/epi/destination`

b)
    `` rsync -O -av `cat list.txt`  --stats --remove-source-files --log-file=log.txt --progress --temp-dir=/temp /home/epi/destination ``

With a) I get an

```
`rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at options.c(1652) [client=3.0.6]`
```

With b) due to the size of the arguments I get

```
`rsync: /usr/bin/rsync: cannot execute [Argument list too long]`
```